# Select box not showing correct value after complete page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

The two fields are being overridden by jQuery OR JS and I'm unable to locate those lines of code.

**Complete Detail:**

The values for those fields (select box and input box) were stored in hidden input fields, and there was jQuery code to pull the value and set in fields after page load. It stopped working somehow and I tried to debug the problem with no luck. So I decided to get rid of JS code and move to PHP, after the migration now field values are being set by PHP. After finishing, I noticed the issue still exist; after spending a lot of time I found that value exist in fields and set to default after complete load. So my best guess says there is something happening with JS. I tried to find string in entire project but don't find any JS/jQuery code which could cause this issue.

**While Loading:** (shows correct value)

```
<select name="days">
   <option value="">Select a Day</option>
   <option value="Mo" selected="selected">Monday</option>
   <option value="Mo">Tuesday</option>
 </select>

 <input type="number" value="10" />
```

**After Load:**

The code is same in inspector but it shows default value for select box "Select a Day" and empty number field.[image]

You can see in attachment, the value "Mo" has selected attribute but it is showing default value. NOTE: It does show correct value "Monday" while loading.

Don't have any idea, what's wrong and never face any problem like this. I've tried several tricks like clearing browser session etc but without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is force the selected value with `jQuery`.

```js
var select = $('[name="days"]');
select.val("");
var options = select.find('option');

$.each(options, function() {
  if ($(this).attr('selected') !== undefined) {
     select.val($(this).val());
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="days">
   <option value="">Select a Day</option>
   <option value="Mo" selected="selected">Monday</option>
   <option value="Mo">Tuesday</option>
 </select>
```

In this code snippet, I am simulating that the null value is selected and I am trying to change it for the option that has the `selected` attribute. Hope it works.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it didn't solve the problem. It adds `selected` attribute. But doesn't show correct value.

Comment: That means there has to be another JS causing the issue. With this code, we are forcing to select the selected value, just like the snippet. Is there any js we should see?

Comment: That's what, I'm trying to find. Unfortunately, it is available in local machine so can't be viewed live. However, you can check above posted screenshot...

Comment: I saw the issue, what I find odd, is that it is not working. Even with my workaround. Well my solution should work for sure if import it as the last js script file or in the bottom of the body. I mean, if it don’t there is something really odd in your page :(

Comment: Well, that's not true because that solution doesn't work in inspector console. If it work there then we could assume that we should execute this at the very end.

Comment: No, I mean, that if it work in the snippet it should work in other environments. If it is being run as the last script and you did clear your cache, then the only other thing that could be causing this behavior is an async call, like an ajax or load() call.

Comment: Well, if we recall our main issue. I mentioned that I set all values in html via php. So they are getting overridden OR set to default by some conflict issue, which I am trying to locate. This could be the reason, why your solution doesn't work in my environment.

Comment: Well, there is a very ugly workaround that could work. Setting a timeout. Of course, this would be just a patch. Adding `setTimeout( function() { ... }, 2000);`. Still I am not sure I would recommend doing this. What you could do, is debug every async call in Chrome and see which one is the culprit. Not much that can be done :(

Comment: How could I inspect aync call in chrome? Are you referring to ajax calls?

Comment: First, go to your page. (Then open Chrome's developer tools.) [http://anti-code.com/devtools-cheatsheet/] Click on the *Network* submenu in the developer tools and then select XHR. Reload your page. There, you will see all async calls. Let me know if you have any problem find the menu. I could add all steps to my answer.

Comment: Was it helpful?

Comment: There isn't any XHR request, there could be some code in any JS file which is causing issue. I'm still struggling and debugging...

Comment: Is it possible, to see your project in Github? All if you don't have a lot of JS files, maybe add them to you question?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use the selected attribute is just to add it.
you don't need to say selected = "selected", just add the attribute
[link to documentation](http://%20https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)

Comment: I mentioned that it works while loading but goes back to default when page is completely loaded. But I still tried your solution but it didn't work! :(